# Height of scrollbar-thumb

Tags: html, css

I need help for the scrollbar.
I want the height of ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb to be 5cm, but I can not fix it.
The height of the::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb is equal to the height of parent.
This is my code.

```
<div class="left-side" id="style-scrollbar">
Nulla sit amet mauris odio. Aenean vitae arcu volutpat, consequat lacus sed, pulvinar augue. Nunc iaculis dapibus fringilla. Vestibulum et mauris quis lacus ultricies elementum ut at ante. Fusce placerat, massa nec tempus pulvinar, nulla tortor vestibulum elit, sit amet volutpat libero massa facilisis nibh. Aenean iaculis ultrices facilisis. Vivamus porta tortor sed mauris ultrices placerat. Suspendisse commodo nibh enim, eget pulvinar risus tristique et. Morbi tincidunt finibus luctus. Sed tincidunt, urna eget malesuada ultricies, dui massa bibendum tortor, a vehicula libero purus in est. Curabitur tincidunt, felis placerat pretium posuere, sapien odio pulvinar libero, nec posuere est nunc egestas diam. Pellentesque efficitur, orci vulputate consectetur imperdiet, justo tortor sollicitudin est, et fermentum leo eros sed diam. Vivamus elementum nisl elit, ac condimentum dolor hendrerit ac.


</div>
.left-side{
  width: 350px;
  margin-right: 22px;
    height:50%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#style-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 9px;
}
#style-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #1e7af5;
    border-radius: 10px;height:5px
    outline: 1px solid #708090;

}

#style-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #b2b2b2;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after you define the `height`, is that intended?

Comment: I made a mistake in writing.

Comment: I want to reduce the height of the blue part.This is working code https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/577232/

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple things I noticed.

1. `height: 5px` didn't have a semi-colon at the end, and was followed by another line. This should normally cause an error in parsing the CSS by the browser.
2. Setting `height: 50%` only works when you have a parent element that has a defined height. Otherwise it will ignore the property.

   > [**Note:** Only calculated values can be inherited. Thus, even if a percentage value is used on the parent property, a real value
   >   (such as a width in pixels for a  value) will be accessible
   >   on the inherited property, not the percentage value.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage)
3. It's a little inefficient to create both ID and class tags for the one element in this example. Just a bit of nitpicking really.

```css
.left-side{
    width: 350px;
    margin-right: 22px;
    height:200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#style-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 9px;
}
#style-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #1e7af5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height:5px;
    outline: 1px solid #708090;

}

#style-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #b2b2b2;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-side" id="style-scrollbar">
Nulla sit amet mauris odio. Aenean vitae arcu volutpat, consequat lacus sed, pulvinar augue. Nunc iaculis dapibus fringilla. Vestibulum et mauris quis lacus ultricies elementum ut at ante. Fusce placerat, massa nec tempus pulvinar, nulla tortor vestibulum elit, sit amet volutpat libero massa facilisis nibh. Aenean iaculis ultrices facilisis. Vivamus porta tortor sed mauris ultrices placerat. Suspendisse commodo nibh enim, eget pulvinar risus tristique et. Morbi tincidunt finibus luctus. Sed tincidunt, urna eget malesuada ultricies, dui massa bibendum tortor, a vehicula libero purus in est. Curabitur tincidunt, felis placerat pretium posuere, sapien odio pulvinar libero, nec posuere est nunc egestas diam. Pellentesque efficitur, orci vulputate consectetur imperdiet, justo tortor sollicitudin est, et fermentum leo eros sed diam. Vivamus elementum nisl elit, ac condimentum dolor hendrerit ac.
</div>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly (my English is bad, sorry), there should be a div parent with a defined height. I tried, but I only made more confusion

Comment: @d.stan Yes, but you can also just set a defined height on the element itself for the purpose of this example. Also I don't fully understand what you want to accomplish. If you want to reduce the height of the scrollbar, you have to set a specific height for the content area, and then you increase the amount of content in the box

Comment: @d.stan To put it simply, the scrollbar's height depends on how much content you have to scroll. You can't manually set it like that. You can however reduce the size of the container that the scrollbar is attached to.